# Символ переноса для WhatsApp

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

Я хочу форматировать текст, который передаю в сообщении при открытии окна (чтобы текст сообщения можно было разбивать по строкам)

```
let text = `&text=Привет. (здесь были уже все варианты переноса) Как дела?`;
window.open(`${url + phone + text}`)
```

Я уже многое пробовал \n, \r\n <br>, пытался кодировать текст посимвольно, короче, не получилось ничего, кто сталкивался, подскажите ещё варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл, %0a - вот этот сработал.